# With in Laravel and Validate double -> operator

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-4, scope

I'm newbye of OOP and Laravel , but i have noticed that the operator with in laravel is used for a lot of things: for example i have found this part of code in the documentation:

```
return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);
```

withErrors? I know that with is used to pass multiple element to a view: is there more that i need to know about this operator?

Another Question: the validate class in php have this type of operator:

```
 $validator->required('You must supply an email address.')->email('You must supply a valid email address')->validate('email', 'Email');
```

why i can use multiple "->" for a instance of the class validator? I know that in this way:

```
$object = new object();

$object->something(); //metod or attribute
```

but i know that it's impossible use the operator "-" for indicate multiple method/attribute for a class(even if it is a library).

thank you for all and i'm sorry for,maybe,the stupid question! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `Redirect::to()` returns an instance of `Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse`. This class has a method `withErrors` which is called in the example.

However this `with*` method is a bit different than the one to pass data to a view. `withErrors` *flashes* the data to the session so it is available for the next request (after the redirect happens)

---

Regarding your second question, this: `$validator->required()->email()` is called **method chaining**. It is used a lot (not only in Laravel) to achieve a nice and brief syntax.

What happens is that the methods return `$this` so you can call the next method on the same object right away.

Let's look at another example:

```
$result = User::where('active', true)->where('name', 'like', 'a%')->get();
```

If we now take a look at the `where()` method in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` you can see that after the where logic happens it returns `$this` so we can continue calling methods.

```
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
{
    // code omitted for brevity

    return $this;
}
```

Many Laravel classes implement this so-called *Fluent Interface* that allows method chaining for nearly every function call. Only methods that have an obvious return value can't be chained. Like retrieving a result with `get()`. Of course it has to return the result and it can't return `$this` as well.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer (by clicking the checkmark next to it) if you this answered your question :)

Comment: it's required 15 point of reputation for check the checkmark to up

Comment: No that's for voting. You can accept an answer with 1 reputation. [Here's how it works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to understand the purpose of `with()` just fine.

As for your second question, you can "chain" object methods if the methods each return the object like this:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    public function myMethod()
    {
        // do stuff
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: i can't use the object $object = new MyClass(); $object->myMethod()->myattribute; Why validate have: $validator->required('You must supply an email address.')->email('You must supply a valid email address')->validate('email', 'Email');

Comment: so, do you think that with have the only option to send multiple variable to the view? I don't thnk so, i have seen that is used to other option